# Is possible to relate Data Categories to custom objects records?

Tags: knowledge, relationships, categories

I have some data in Knowledge and Answers that I'd love to relate to other data in custom objects?

Is it possible to refer data categories from custom objects, besides sort of manually (and maintaining) building a multi-select that mirrors the data categories?

Comment: running into the need for this same requirement.  Did you every figure anything out?  Or did you just go with the Multi-select picklist approach?

Comment: Sadly ended up using custom objects for everything instead of knowledge

Answer (score 0):

No, Datacategories were designed as part of Salesforce Knowledge:

> Data categories are used in Salesforce Knowledge (articles and article
>   translations), Ideas, Answers, and Chatter Answers to help classify
>   and find articles, questions, or ideas. You can use data categories to
>   control access to a particular set of articles, questions or ideas.

Please find salesforce's documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=category_whatis.htm&type=0)

Answer (score 0):

Much has changed since this question was originally asked. The simplest way to do what you're asking would be to update your Knowledge to Lightning Knowledge which is an actual object where you could create the kind of relationships you're speaking about such as M-D or Look-up relationships to Custom Objects. Lightning Knowledge also supports its own record types and much more.

Thank being said, I believe there are ways of doing what I believe you're asking with Knowledge in its current state. Knowledge is about taking content from a variety of sources and putting it into context. This can be done for example with emails received from Cases as a source and adding additional content such as notes from Cases to provide a document that provides guidance on how to solve a particular problem or troubleshoot a particular symptom. I believe you're asking if the content can be linked from a custom object. According to the [documentation on custom field types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_custom_field_types.htm&type=5):

> **Lookup Relationship**
>
> Creates a relationship between two records so you can associate them with each other. For example, opportunities have a lookup relationship with cases that lets you associate a particular case with an opportunity. A lookup relationship creates a field that allows agents to click a lookup icon and select another record from a popup window. On the associated record, you can then display a related list to show all the records that are linked to it. You can create lookup relationship fields that link to users, standard objects, or custom objects. If a lookup field references a record that has been deleted, Salesforce clears the value of the lookup field by default. Alternatively, you can choose to prevent records from being deleted if they’re in a lookup relationship. You can make this field required so an agent must enter a value before saving an article.

Clearly, based on the above, you can link to custom objects. From the same page, it states you can also attach files but you cannot attach Salesforce CRM Content files using the File field.

I'll add that using Topics would be an additional way of relating your Knowledge articles to Custom Objects. See [Enable Topics for Articles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_topics.htm&type=5) for more on the subject.